# Jupyter widgets vs JupyterLab Extension?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I know that JupyterLab is the next-generation web-based UI for Project Jupyter and it's based on the Jupyter Notebook and Architecture, and *it will eventually replace the classic Jupyter Notebook.*

I am a bit confused about the differences and relationships between **Jupyter widgets** and **JupyterLab Extensions**:

- Will JupyterLab Extensions eventually replace those Jupyter widgets for using interactive Notebook?
- Is Jupyter Widgets only for classic Jupyter Notebook? Or is Widgets just one type of the Extensions for JupyterLab?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not an expert on Jupyter extensions, but I think the following is accurate (please correct me if someone knows otherwise).

Jupyter widgets are actually implemented using an extension.

The main difference between widgets and other extensions is that
the Python kernel in a notebook can easily interact with a widget
-- the kernel can "call in" to the widget and the widget can "call back" to the kernel.  For example the kernel can change the text label for a button in the widget and a button press on the widget can cause
Python code to execute in the kernel.

For example the following notebook creates a widget with a click callback to python which calls back to Javascript to change the appearance of the widget:

https://github.com/AaronWatters/jp_proxy_widget/blob/master/notebooks/hello%20proxy%20world.ipynb

Extensions do not automatically build in ways for a Python kernel process in a notebook to interact with the extension instance, although it is possible to implement them.

Comment: A bit old but I think it can be useful:
There are 2 types of extensions, labextensions (frontend in Javascript) and serverextensions (backend in Python).
Jupyter widgets is a project using both, one to display the widgets in the notebooks and one to communicate with the kernel. The communication between them is done with a websocket, managed by lumino (the new phosphorJS).